# Swift swipe through photos randomly

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, swipe

Originally I had a different post, just wanted to redo it to clean it up.

[image]

This is more or less the layout I wanted to go with. Imagine the first imageview had dog pictures, the second one had cat pictures and the third one had rabbit pictures. three folders contain a group of three separate sets of pictures.

What is the best way to set it up so I can randomly swipe, lets say the first image view where it would only show pictures of dogs.

What I am asking is, is there a certain way to create the file structures or link the pictures to each image view?

I have the basics of the random (something with a 4 in it don't remember the method exactly) and the basics of swipe, just was looking for help with linking the photos and file structure.

Please let me know if this still doesn't make sense.

Thank you

**EDIT**

after messing with this this is where I am at:

with a very simple array basically

```
catsArray: [String] = ["catpic1","catpic2"......]
```

then I have it set up as

```
        let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(catArray.count)))

    if (sender.direction == .Right)
    {
        self.catImageView.image = UIImage(named: catArray[randomIndex])
    }
```

just me hacking things off the internet. now I am running into an issue. after a few swipes I get a null images or its just blank. Why is that?

now that I have some of this set up I am debating if I should just use parse for a server or if there is a better way.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your question is far too vague. Are you worried about memory? If so, you should not load the images into an array. Instead load the image names, and load each image as it is swiped on-screen. You might want to load the current image and the next image so it's already in memory and can be displayed without lag.

Are you talking about using a UIPageViewController? That's a good class for managing a set of pages that you can scroll through. There is a sample app from Apple called PhotoScroller that illustrates that technique, along with tiling the images so you can display large images and handle zooming and panning. (The app is written in Objective-C however.)

### EDIT:

Your updates make your question a little clearer.

There are lots of ways to handle this. Here's 1.

Create 3 separate folders, one for cats, one for dogs, and one for rabbits. (in your app's documents directory, or in the bundle, if the images will be shipped with the app.)

Use NSFileManager to create 3 separate arrays of filenames. Take a look at the methods `contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:includingPropertiesForKeys:options:error:` and `contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:`. You should be able to make either of those work.

Then you'll need to scramble your arrays of filenames to create a randomized order. You can use one of the block-based sort methods where your block uses a random number to determine the sort order of each pair of objects.

Finally you'll need to implement the swipe to switch.

It sounds like you are beginner so this is a lot to work through. You should break the problem into pieces and tackle them one at a time.

Comment: I will reply here then edit the main post as I find words. basically what I am looking for is i have three folders with pictures. for example one is cats one is dogs and one is bunnies. I want to be able to have three UIimageview that use each separate folder. each on you can randomly swipe through each folder separate. meaning how do I set it up so one imageview doesnt scroll through all three folders?

Comment: Awesome. I am still new to swift an Xcode, as well as file management. I will play with this and see if I can't get it working

Comment: hey is what i Want? https://github.com/DharmeshKheni/Show-Document-Directory/blob/master/show%20Document%20Files/ViewController.swift

Comment: screw it. Im just going to put each image in one by one for now.

Answer (score 0):

Either approach will work. It's probably a good exercise to write both versions. You'd learn from it.

Comment: If you are talking about scrolling vs swiping thats not really the question I was asking and I guess I need to edit again. If I import all the pictures in three separate folders, I just don't know how to separate the photos in three categories i.e. array or whatnot so the stay separate when linking them to each separate image view.